# How to indent multiple lines above the cursor in Vim?

Tags: vim, indentation

I know that `3>>` will indent the current line and the two lines below the cursor. How do I indent the current line and the two lines above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be working with

```
:-2,.>
```

or

```
>2k
```

Or, select the line and the two above in visual mode and then just type <kbd>></kbd>.

[`:he shift-left-right`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#shift-left-right) has more information about shifting.
[`:he :ranges`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#E14) tells you more about specifying ranges for a command.

Comment: Nice answer. Also, `k` could be any of `hjkl` to denote the direction of the command. For example: `4gUl` would upper-case the next 4 characters while `4gUh` would upper-case the previous 4.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>2>k</kbd> (or <kbd>>2k</kbd>)

Remember from the manual,

> ```
>                           *>>*
> >>            Shift [count] lines one 'shiftwidth' rightwards.
> ```

But also,

> ```
>                           *>*
> >{motion}     Shift {motion} lines one 'shiftwidth' rightwards.
> ```